# Format the actual HTML to be readable with SeamFramwork

Tags: html, jsf, richfaces, format, seam2

Is there a way to format the actual HTML into readable (nicely formatted) text when generating xhtml pages from SeaMFramework.

I want to be able to rightclick on my webpages and view-source where the html and javascript is well formated (tabbed, new lines). I'm using JSF and Richfaces which genreates their own html and javascripts which I want more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`JTidyFilter`](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/multiproject/jtidyservlet/filter.html) for this. Download [jtidyservlet.jar](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/nightly/jtidyservlet-r8-SNAPSHOT.jar), drop it in `/WEB-INF/lib` and register the filter as follows in `web.xml`:

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>jTidyfilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.w3c.tidy.servlet.filter.JTidyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>jTidyfilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern> <!-- Or whatever you're using for JSF -->
</filter-mapping>
```

I would personally not care about this. The filter has a significant performance impact and browser's developer tools like Chrome/Firebug/IE9 already shows nicely formatted HTML on F12. It are anyway the (puristic) developers who care about this, not "dumb" endusers.